# Ajax json Selector for CheckBoxList get values

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, checkboxlist

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: 0
    });
    $("#btnGetData").click(function() {
        updateProgress();
        var intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 5000);
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: 0
        });
        $("#result").text(' ');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ListaInformes.aspx/GetText",
            data: "{fechain: '" + $('#txtFechaInicio').val() + "', fechafin: '" + $('#txtFechaFin').val() + "', tiporeporte: '" + $('#DDLTipoInforme').val() + "', segmento:'" + $('#DDLSegmento').val() + "', categoria:'" + $("#<%=ddlCategorias.ClientID%>").val() + "', area:'" + $("#<%=ddlarea.ClientID %>").val() + "', idusuario:'<%=Session("
            IdUsuario ") %>', tipofecha: '" + $('#RBL_TipoFecha input:checked').val() + "',regional:'" + $("#<% = CheckBoxRegional.ClientID %> input:checkbox[checked=true]").serializeArray() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", 100);
                $("#result").html(msg.d);
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function updateProgress() {
    var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
    if (value < 100) {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", value + 1);
    }
}​
</script>
```

I'm using JSON, jQuery and ASP.net to create a checkboxlist type control, which is filled by a database. The problem is that I create a selector to know if they are selected or not and also know that value.

I need you in the region are stored variable check that assets and their values??  Are, so far only tells me which ones are active, but not its value.

The application is as follows:

Selector jquery para checkboxlist

```
<div id="main">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr id="tr_fechausuario" runat="server" align="left">
      <td colspan="2">
        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="50%">Fecha de Inicio&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtFechaInicio" runat="server"
              CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td width="50%">Fecha de Fin&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtFechaFin" runat="server"
              CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2" runat="server" align="left">
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr1" runat="server" align="left">
      <td class="style3">Seleccione el tipo de consulta</td>
      <td class="style1">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBL_TipoInforme" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"
        AutoPostBack="True">
          <asp:ListItem Value="0">Informe de Casos</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="1">Informe Histórico</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="spacer1" runat="server" align="left">
      <td colspan="2" class="style6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_spacer" runat="server" align="left">
      <td class="style7">Seleccione el criterio de las fechas</td>
      <td>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBL_TipoFecha" runat="server">
          <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">Fecha de Creación</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="2">Fecha de Vencimiento</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="3">Fecha de Solución</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="spacer2" runat="server" align="left" visible="True">
      <td class="style5">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_tipoinforme" runat="server" align="left" visible="False">
      <td class="style8">Seleccione el tipo de informe</td>
      <td class="style2">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLTipoInforme" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
        DataSourceID="SQLDS_Informes" DataTextField="iet_NombreInforme" DataValueField="iet_TipoInforme"
        Enabled="False" CssClass="textbox" Height="20px" Width="548px"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLDS_Informes" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bdcmp_EcopetrolCRMConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="eco_spInformeEstadisticaConsulta" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
          <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2" Name="Donde_1" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="96" Name="IdUsuario_2" SessionField="IdUsuario"
            Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="TipoInforme_3" Type="Int32" />
          </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="spacer3" runat="server" align="left" visible="True">
      <td class="style4" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_segmento" runat="server" align="left" visible="false">
      <td class="style7">Seleccione el segmento</td>
      <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSegmento" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="textbox"
        AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Tr3" runat="server" align="left" visible="True">
      <td class="style4" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <%-- Se añade nuevo campos regional--%>
      <tr id="tr_regional" runat="server" visible="False">
        <td>Selecciones la Regional</td>
        <td>
          <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxRegional" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small"></asp:CheckBoxList>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLRegional" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="Tr7">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_Categorias" runat="server" align="left" visible="false">
        <td class="style7">Seleccione la Categoria</td>
        <td>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategorias" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"
          Width="200px" ToolTip="Seleccione la Categoria"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Rv_Categoria"
          runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCategorias" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*"
          InitialValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Visible="False"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="Tr4" runat="server" align="left" visible="True">
        <td class="style4" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_Area" runat="server" align="left" visible="false">
        <td class="style7">Seleccione el Area</td>
        <td>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlarea" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="textbox"
          AutoPostBack="False"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <div id="progressbar"></div>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <br />
  <center>
    <asp:Button ID="btnGetData" runat="server" Text="Generar Informe" CssClass="button"
    ForeColor="#336699" Enabled="false" />
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SO. Nomás una pregunta, qué trataste de decir aquí/Hey, welcome to SO. Just a question, what did you try to say here?: _I need you in the region are stored variable check that assets and their values??_

Comment: Create a variable called regional in JavaScript code that is where I need to be almacenene the value that can capture the CheckBoxList

Comment: ask me in spanish, no problem.

Comment: Hola, lo que sucede es que necesito capturar los valores del checkboxlist por medio de los selectores que estan en el ajax, lo estaba haciendo asi: `regional:'" + $("#<% = CheckBoxRegional.ClientID %> input:checkbox[checked=true]").serializeArray()` pero de esta manera no me funciona. Gracias por tu ayuda